# Appium - Finding elements isn't consistent

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I experience very annoying situation when writing tests in Appium for Android app for now:
Sometimes, some elements (same 2 elements) not being found consistenly every test run.

This is my test code:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("com.*****.android.g******:id/passwordText"),"Code"));
    MobileElement we = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.******.android.*******:id/passwordText");
    we.click();
    we.sendKeys(password);
    CodePage codePage = new CodePage(driver);
    codePage.loginBtn.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("com.*****.android.*******:id/action_done"), "FINISH"));
    BaseTutorialPage btp = new BaseTutorialPage(driver);
    btp.finishBtn.click();
```

Here you can see the 2 problematic fields: we (which is pin number field), and finishbtn, which is another button to click on. 
I tried using several Exepected conditions to the wait section, but it all behave the same, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

And here I set the caps:

```
    File app = new File(f, "app-debug.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"test");
    cap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 60 * 10);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.*******.android.*****.registartion.LoginActivity");
    AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    return driver;
```

Versions I use: 
Appium 1.7.2 
java-client 5.0.4 (tried also the latest BETA)

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly the error that you get?

Comment: I just get element not found timeout. I see it in the device, I can click on it using the Appium Inspector, but using the code it doesnt do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for answer, I just upgraded automationName to uiautomator2 and it resolved the problem.